# delete a folder while uninstalling my application, windows 7

Tags: vb.net

I have developed an VB application for windows. The application creates a folder say "C:\My_Folder", when I run the application. I want to delete that folder when I uninstall my application(through control panel > uninstall ). How can I implement that? 
Thanks...

Comment: Creating folders directly under the root of a drive is not a good idea in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

When you creating Setup project you have option to add files.
If you added files on it then they will automatic delete when uninstall.

If you need to save some data Use Registry that is the common way to save form events in computer.